# How could i get key ,value pair in window phone?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

Hi there I have a string return from url like that :

```
{ "Title": "Star Wars", "Year": "1977", "Rated":"3" }
```

How can I pick up such title, rating, Year without using Json library?

Comment: That's not valid JSON anyway, as `"Rating"` is not associated with anything.

Comment: Why do you want parse JSON without using JSON library? JSON.NET is PCL compatible. What will happen with your algorithm if you'll receive indented string?

Comment: pickypg : I have just edited

Comment: Then why don't want you to use a JSON library? If it's an assignment, then that's okay, but you need to show what you have tried. If it's for a project, then you should definitely be using a JSON library.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to do it this way :

```
var str = @"{ ""Title"": ""Star Wars"", ""Year"": ""1977"", ""Rated"":""3"" }";
//remove "{" and "}" from string
var result = str.Trim('{', '}');
//separate each property-value pairs, and remove leading & trailing white spaces
var pairs = result.Split(',').Select(o => o.Trim()).ToArray();
foreach (var pair in pairs)
{
    //separate key from it's value and remove leading & trailing white spaces
    var keyValue = pair.Split(':').Select(o => o.Trim()).ToArray();
    //print result
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
}
```

**UPDATE :**

I agree with @pickypg comment, manually doing set of string manipulation operations isn't the ultimate way to handle JSON. This is better only on specific case: handling small JSON containing 'safe' string. If you're looking for general & robust approach, no one will argue with suggestion to use proven JSON library like [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/). Also agree about using `.Trim()` instead of twice `Replace()`, hence updated my code a bit.

Comment: I suspect that this works for the given example, but movies that contain punctuation like `"O Brother, Where Art Thou?"` will not work. This is why he should use a JSON library. PS: `str.Trim('{', '}', ' ')` would be faster _and safer_ than the two-step `Replace`.

Comment: @pickypg agree, this is only alternative for specific Json input.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to parse Json you should use a library to do it properly. Well, this solution can be a little overkill but you could do something like this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\"(?<field>.+?)\":\\s*\"(?<value>.*?)\"");
Match match = regex.Match("{ \"Title\": \"Star Wars\", \"Year\": \"1977\", \"Rated\":\"3\" }");
while (match.Success)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Field: "+match.Groups["field"].Value+ ", Value: "+match.Groups["value"].Value);
   match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not valid json, you'd have to manually parse like split.

```
Parse error on line 4:
..."1977",    "Rated"}
---------------------^
Expecting ':'
```

Try this

```
string[] words = s.Split(' ');
foreach (string word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Class code added ignore above:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Rated { get; set; }
}
```

using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: The reason you do not want to do this is because that is not foolproof. You would split `"Star Wars"` into `"Star` and `Wars"`, likely then mistaking Wars for an unwanted key like `"Rated"`. Similarly, splitting by `','` would likely cause similar issues for other titles.

Comment: agreed, its not good , now the Json is valid best to create a class and use json.net serializer, IMHO                                      public class RootObject
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Rated { get; set; }
}

Comment: Mostly agree, but `Year` should likely be something like an `int` and `Rating` can probably be something else, like an enumeration (I'm guessing it's representative of something like 5 stars).

Comment: Yup but the json needs to be like so and it's not  otherwise the classes wont match I think ?